# Conversión de números enteros a romanos en Python

Tags: python

me podrían ayudar a entender este código? Estoy algo perdido en el bucle for, no estoy entendiendo bien. Supongamos que le meto un 95 a la función, el for va a iterar sobre las lista recuperando los elementos, hasta que llega a 90, 95 es mayor a 90 así que entra dentro del bucle, después a la variable roman se le suma r que vale XC y a integer se le resta i, o sea 95-90=5, después el for sigue iterando y los números (i) que siguen no son menores a 5 así que se sale del bucle y retorna el romano (¿Por qué retorna XCV y no XC?)

```
integer_roman = [(1000, 'M'), (900, 'CM'), (500, 'D'), (400, 'CD'), (100, 'C'), (90, 'XC'), (50, 'L'), (40, 'XL'), (10, 'X'), (9, 'IX'), (5, 'V'), (4, 'IV'), (1, 'I')]

def integer_to_roman(integer):
    roman = '' # Se declara la variable roman y se le asigna una cadena vacía.

    while integer > 0: # Mientras el número ingresado sea mayor a cero.
        for i, r in integer_roman: # Iteramos en la lista integer_roman sobre cada par entero-romano.
            while integer >= i: # Mientras el número sea mayor o igual al iterable i. 95 >= 90 -> roman = XC -> integer = 5
                roman += r # A la variable roman le sumamos lo que vale r.
                integer -= i # A la variable num le sumamos lo que vale r.

    return roman # Regresamos el número romano.

integer = int(input('Ingrese un número entero: '))
print(f'El número ingresado es: {integer_to_roman(integer)}')
```

Comment: Ojo, acordate que al salir de `while integer >= i`, seguís estando en `for i, r in integer_roman`... Atendé en dónde está el `return`.

Comment: 95-90 es 5, el valor de `integer` ahora es 5. Entonces sale del `while` más chico y recién vuelve ingresar cuando se cumple: `5 >= 5`, al ser iguales ingresa y termina agregandole V a tu resultado, por el cual es correcto que devuelta `XCV`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedó claro.